# How to transfer Vivado projects properly between PCs?

Tags: file-transfer, vivado

I have to transfer my Vivado Project to a nother Pc for showing to my Professor.

Vivado loads our Project normally and also imports all Data.
But if we run the synthesis this error occurs.

(® [Common 17-1294] Unable to create a directory
[F:/Uni/Speicher_Uni_Programme/DigiSchaltTech/GitLinked/Uni_Digi_Schalt_Tech/Prak
tikum/V2/DSPV2/DSPV2.srcs/utils_1/imports/synth_11].

I know it accrues because the file paths changed, but I was not able to fix it.
I also checked the project XPR file. Actually found one mention of the old file path, and changed it to the new one but nothing changed.

The Logs told me that Vivado is still trying to import stuff from the old file path.

I assume there is a sub-boot file or something similar where it does not change the file path as it should.

How do I fix this problem in the Future?
Is there an easy way to transfer projects between PCs without changing multiple files?

Comment: Since Vivado is an FPGA design tool this might be more answerable on https://electronics.stackexchange.com where the FPGA designers are :)

Comment: @user253751 thanks for that tip. I haven‘t heard of this difference before. So I will repost that question there. Hopefully, I will get an answer somehow.

Comment: Link to the posted Question on stackexchange https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/641909/325838

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**For an answhere with pictures visit https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/642028/325838**

**Method 1:** *(delete some folders)*

1. Close Vivado
2. Go to the Vivado Project Path >> open the ***Project*.runs** Folder
3. **Delete** all **synth** and **impl** Folders
4. **Restart your Project** and run all the synthesis again

Now Vivado should be able to create a new synthesis (and new Folders) because it does not find old synthesis linked paths.

**Method 2:** *(creat a new synthesis)*

1. **Create** a **new synthesis**
2. **make** the **new synthesis active** *(right-click on the new synthesis)*
3. **delete the old synthesis**, if not possible, delete the folder of the old synthesis like shown in *Method 1*.

**Method 3:**
*(The easiest, but only possible on the Pc where you created the original Vivado Project)*

1. create an archive of the project *(File >> Project >> Archive)*
2. **Deselect *Include run results*** *(this should not include your synthesis data in the Archive)*
3. de-Zip the archive on the new PC and run the Project file. *(Now it should work)*

**sadly you still have to redo in all Methods the synthesis, implementation and Bitstream generation again**

*If none of this works, try to also reset the Output Products and regenerate the Output Products before trying all steps of one Method again.*

I hope this will help others with the same problem because it took us some time to figure it out and we also couldn't find some solutions online.